# Next JS Image component doesn't load svg beforehand / disable "Lazy Loading"

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, next.js

**The problem is only with svg images. Works well with other formats**

Hello! I am using an Image component in nextjs. I ran into a problem while trying to add an svg image to a modal window. When I open the modal the image is missing and it takes about a second to load. This happens every time the modal window is reopened.

I think this is due to "Lazy Loading". This option is very inappropriate in this case. I would like to load the image as soon as the user enters the site, and not during the opening of the modal window

I have tried several ways.

1. assign Image properties to the component

   ```
        ` 

       <Image
        src={Email}
        alt={"Picture"}
        width={20}
        height={20}
        loading={"eager"}
        priority
    />

       `
   ```

Problem still exists. Loading an image takes a second of time after each modal window is opened

2. Load an image in the main component, and pass it through props to the modal window.
   Problem still exists

**My svg image is very small. I have also tried other images**